# IOS Update through tethering

Tags: ios, software-update

I am not having WiFi. To update to IOS 11 iphone needs a WiFi connection. 
My idea is to use the Iphone for tethering and connect it "to itself". Will it work? Can I connect my Iphone the WiFi it makes itself and than do the update via mobile network?

Answer (score 2):

No.

It’s not possible to connect to an iPhone to its own Personal Hotspot network as a client. iPhone can only be connected to one Wi-Fi network, so any attempt to join a network will turn off Personal Hotspot.

You can tether to any other device, though and get your download on cellular data from the other plan.